# Text problem in template machine

Tags: php, templates, text

I have this code:

```
class template
{
    public $template,$prefix,$replace;
    function __construct($template, $prefix)
    {
        $this->prefix = $prefix;
        $this->template = $template;
    }
    public function SetValue($name, $replace)
    {
        $this->replace["#".$name."#"] = $replace;
    }
    public function Tempclude($found) 
    { 
        $file = "styles/main/".$found[1].'.html';

        if(!file_exists($file))     
            exit("the template '" . $found[1] . "' wasn't found."); 
        return file_get_contents($file); 
    }
    public function finish($stream = "normal")
    {
        if($stream == "folder")
            $code = file_get_contents("../styles/main/".$this->template.".html");
        else 
            $code = file_get_contents("styles/main/".$this->template.".html");

        $code = preg_replace_callback("@<pb:include=\"(.*)\">@iuU", array($this, 'Tempclude'), $code);

        if(is_array($this->replace))
            $code = str_replace(array_keys($this->replace), $this->replace, $code);

        $code = str_replace("\r\n", "", $code);
        $code = str_replace("   ", "", $code);
        echo $code;
    }
}
```

If I type in the Template some simple text, the page turns white with nothing inside.

What is the problem?

Comment: Try to add error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1); to yours code at the beginning and check what is the error. I guess there is a fatal one and you have got error reporting turned off. Cheers ;)

Comment: Try to rename your class, I think that name of the class can't be "template" this word might be reserved... The other thing is did you included / required file with this class in your script? And there might be problem with syntax as well "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected..."

Comment: No i lost ; at the and of you code..

Comment: I recommend you set the error_reporting and display_errors in your php.ini file - if the error happens at the script-level, it won't be able to "see" your attempts to adjust them there.

Comment: Not to be the party pooper here, but why don't you try an existing template engine, such as Twig?

Answer (score 0):

it is no the problem. 
Try doing this:

```
$template = new template("index", ""); 

$template->SetValue("notice", "notice:"); 

$template->finish();
```

and index.html:

```
<pb:include="header"> 
    hhh 
    #Slider# 
<pb:include="footer">
```

its work. 
if you change index.html to:

```
<pb:include="header"> 
    <div id="hh"> 
        hhh 
    </div> 
    #Slider#
```

it return a white list with somthing inside.

Answer (score 0):

1. I have found the unquoted constant shows warning (depends on php configuration, WAMP does)
2. In the edited code that you have problem with errors, only quote the two constants in the begining it should work okay, test it like this:

   $template = new template("index", "");
   $template->SetValue("notice", "notice:");
   $template->finish();
3. folder structure: styles/main must be provided. These files must be found inside main: index.html, footer.html, header.html must be privided

When everything okay, please try to delete any uneccessary comments or answers. 
Thank you!